# Flow provides null from room database but it should have data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I started building my app using Room, Flow, LiveData and Coroutines, and have come across something odd: what I'm expecting to be a value flow  actually has one null item in it.

My setup is as follows:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface BookDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = :id")
    fun getBook(id: Long): Flow<Book>
}
```

```kotlin
@Singleton
class BookRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val bookDao: BookDao
) {
    fun getBook(id: Long) = bookDao.getBook(id).filterNotNull()
}
```

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class BookDetailViewModel @Inject internal constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val bookRepository: BookRepository,
    private val chapterRepository: ChapterRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
    val bookID: Long = savedStateHandle.get<Long>(BOOK_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY)!!
    val book = bookRepository.getBook(bookID).asLiveData()

    fun getChapters(): LiveData<PagingData<Chapter>> {
        val lastChapterID = book.value.let { book ->
            book?.lastChapterID ?: 0L
        }
        val chapters = chapterRepository.getChapters(bookID, lastChapterID)
        return chapters.asLiveData()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val BOOK_ID_SAVED_STATE_KEY = "bookID"
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class BookDetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private var queryJob: Job? = null
    private val viewModel: BookDetailViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        load()
    }

    private fun load() {
        queryJob?.cancel()
        queryJob = lifecycleScope.launch() {
            val bookName = viewModel.book.value.let { book ->
                book?.name
            }
            binding.toolbar.title = bookName
            Log.i(TAG, "value: $bookName")
        }
        viewModel.book.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { book ->
            binding.toolbar.title = book.name
            Log.i(TAG, "observe: ${book.name}")
        }

    }
}
```

Then I get a null value in `lifecycleScope.launch` while `observe(viewLifecycleOwner)` gets a normal value.

I think it might be because of sync and async issues, but I don't know the exact reason, and how can I use `LiveData<T>.value` to get the value?

Because I want to use it in `BookDetailViewModel.getChapters` method.

**APPEND**: In the best practice example of `Android Jetpack` ([Sunflower](https://github.com/android/sunflower)), `LiveData.value` ([createShareIntent](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/PlantDetailFragment.kt#L127) method of PlantDetailFragment) works fine.

**APPEND 2**: The `getChapters` method returns a paged data (`Flow<PagingData<Chapter>>`). If the book triggers an update, it will cause the page to be refreshed again, confusing the UI logic.

**APPEND 3**: I found that when I bind `BookDetailViewModel` with `DataBinding`, `BookDetailViewModel.book` works fine and can get `book.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LiveData.value` has extremely limited usefulness because you might be reading it when no value is available yet.

You’re checking the `value` of your LiveData before it’s source Flow can emit its first value, and the initial value of a LiveData before it emits anything is null.

If you want `getChapters` to be based on the book LiveData, you should do a transformation on the book LiveData. This creates a LiveData that under the hood observes the other LiveData and uses that to determine what it publishes. In this case, since the return value is another LiveData, `switchMap` is appropriate. Then if the source book Flow emits another version of the book, the LiveData previously retrieved from `getChapters` will continue to emit, but it will be emitting values that are up to date with the current book.

```
fun getChapters(): LiveData<PagingData<Chapter>> = 
    Transformations.switchMap(book) { book ->
        val lastChapterID = book.lastChapterID
        val chapters = chapterRepository.getChapters(bookID, lastChapterID)
        chapters.asLiveData()
    }
```

---

Based on your comment, you can call `take(1)` on the Flow so it will not change the LiveData book value when the repo changes.

```
val book = bookRepository.getBook(bookID).take(1).asLiveData()
```

But maybe you want the Book in that LiveData to be able to be changed when the repo changes, and what you want is that the Chapters LiveData retrieved previously does not change? So you need to manually get it again if you want it to be based on the latest Book? If that's the case, you don't want to be using `take(1)` there which would prevent the book from appearing updated in the `book` LiveData.

I would personally in that case use a SharedFlow instead of LiveData, so you could avoid retrieving the values twice, but since you're currently working with LiveData, here's a possible solution that doesn't require you to learn those yet. You could use a temporary Flow of your LiveData to easily get its current or first value, and then use that in a `liveData` builder function in the `getChapters()` function.

```
fun getChapters(): LiveData<PagingData<Chapter>> = liveData {
    val singleBook = book.asFlow().first()
    val lastChapterID = singleBook.lastChapterID
    val chapters = chapterRepository.getChapters(bookID, lastChapterID)
    emitSource(chapters)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in the best practice example of `Android Jetpack` ([Sunflower](https://github.com/android/sunflower)), `LiveData.value` ([createShareIntent](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/PlantDetailFragment.kt#L127) method of PlantDetailFragment) works fine.

Comment: Not every Google example is perfect. Some of their Code Labs are riddled with errors, typos, and inconsistencies. In this case, the example works because the race condition they’ve created will *usually* be fine, because it would be hard to press the Share button in the menu so fast after the Fragment loads that there hasn’t been time for the value to be read from the database yet. If you’re calling your `getChapters()` directly during one of the beginning lifecycle functions on the Fragment, you are more likely to lose in the race condition.

Comment: I had not browsed Sunflower before. It’s really disappointing they would include such fragile code in something that’s supposed to illustrate best practices.

Comment: No wonder, I got it, thanks again.

Comment: But the original answer is also not what I want, I don't want the value of book to be updated. Because the `getChapters` method returns a paged data (`Flow<PagingData<Chapter>>`), if the book will trigger an update, it will cause the page to refresh.

Comment: I expanded on the answer.

Comment: Great, that's what I wanted, thanks a lot.